# New XCode is proving problematic for Stanford CS 193P

Tags: computer-science, xcode4.5, cs193p

I am working through the CS 193P course from 2011 from Stanford University and much of the code is not working. When I updated to the new XCode, none of the button segues I program work and trying to implement a scroll view today went interestingly. Is there any way to revert to the old XCode or some workaround I should know so I can at least follow along with the lessons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a free iBook from Stanford on iBookstore that supplements the course material for iOS 6 and XCode 4.5 : [Editor's Cut webpage](http://editorscut.com/Books/003ipadiphone/003ipadiphone-details.html)

It's not by the same author, and there are differences in the order things are done, but it is very well written, has animated walkthroughs, and does an excellent job of explaining what has changed and why. A lot less confusing than trying figure out the version differences on one's own while learning a new technology. Of course, as an iBook, it is only viewable on an iOS device, and only usefully so on an iPad.